# Traverse a tree like array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree

I have an array that looks like a tree structure. It's array of objects, where objects have an array of children and the children further have an array of children. Below is the example. I have tried to use recursion in the problem but couldn't get the desired result.

```
[
    {
      parentId: null,
      children: [
        {
          parentId: 267,
          children: [
            {
              parentId: 268,
              children: [
                {
                  parentId: 270,
                  children: null,
                }
              ],
            },
            {
              parentId: 268,
              children: [
                {
                  parentId: 269,
                  children: null,
                }
              ],
            }
          ],
        }
      ],
    },
   ...
   ...
  ];
```

I would like to traverse through this array and in every object I need to add a key and a value.

E.g **open : 'fa fa-open'**

Every Object in the resulting array must have the above key.

Comment: do you want to get a new array or just insert the property into the existing array and children?

Comment: Into an existing array. I was also not able to copy this array as some error of circular json popped up

Answer (score 3):

[image]Please take a look at code in the link below it recursively traverses through all children and inserts open: 'fa fa-open'
https://codesandbox.io/s/o4jvxloy7q

Comment: Is there a way that i could add icon only to a particular parent and its children if a parentid is given

Comment: @RenilBabu yes you can pass parentId for as argument to function and where open key is getting added make it a conditional.

Comment: But i think it will be only one level. I need all the childrens and further childrens of the given parentid not to have fa fa-open

Answer (score 2):

This type of problem is perfect to learn about mutual recursion.

First, we make some way to `traverse` a single `node` and its `children` using a higher-order function `f` –

```
const traverse = (f, { children = [], ...node }) =>
  f ({ ...node, children: children.map (c => traverse (f, c)) })
```

For example, add property `hello` set to `'world'` to each node –

```
traverse
  ( node => ({ ...node, hello: 'world' })
  , { a: 1, children: [ { b: 2 } ] }
  )

// { a: 1
// , children:
//     [ { b: 2
//       , children: []
//       , hello: 'world'
//       }
//     ]
//  }
```

But this only works for a *single* node. You have an *array* of nodes, so –

```
const traverseAll = (f, nodes = []) =>
  nodes.map (node => traverse (f, node))
```

When you look back at `traverse`, we see we repeated ourselves (in **bold**) –

```
const traverse = (f, { children = [], ...node }) =>
  f ({ ...node, children: children.map (c => traverse (f, c)) })

const traverseAll = (f, nodes = []) =>
  nodes.map (node => traverse (f, node))
```

Using a *mutually* recursive definition, we write a harmonious pair –

```
const traverseAll = (f, nodes = []) =>
  nodes.map (node => traverse (f, node))

const traverse = (f, { children = [], ...node }) =>
  f ({ ...node, children: traverseAll (f, children) })
```

Verify the complete program in your browser below –

```js
const traverseAll = (f, nodes = []) =>
  nodes.map (node => traverse (f, node))

const traverse = (f, { children = [], ...node }) =>
  f ({ ...node, children: traverseAll (f, children) })

const nodes =
  [ { id: 1
    , children:
        [ { id: 2
          , children: []
          }
        , { id: 3
          , children:
              [ { id: 4
                , children: []
                }
              ]
          }
        ]
     }
   , { id: 5
     , children: []
     }
   ]
   
console.log
  ( traverseAll
      ( node => ({ ...node, open: 'fa fa-open' })
      , nodes
      )
  )

// [ { id: 1
//   , children: 
//       [ { id: 2, children: [], open: 'fa fa-open' },
//         { id: 3
//         , children:
//             [ { id: 4
//               , children: []
//               , open: 'fa fa-open'
//               }
//             ]
//         , open: 'fa fa-open'
//         }
//       ]
//   , open: 'fa fa-open'
//   }
// , { id: 5
//   , children: []
//   , open: 'fa fa-open'
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = [
  {
    parentId: 123,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    parentId: 345,
    children: [],
  },
  {
    parentId: 1567,
    children: [],
  },
];

data.forEach(item => item.open = "new value")
console.log(data)
```

Comment: This code can be done only for a flat array. Question is about nested one. e.g the children will have children just like a tree structure.

Comment: I misunderstood  the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create recursive function with `forEach` loop that takes data and an object and assigns that object to each object in your data.

```js
const data = [{"parentId":null,"children":[{"parentId":267,"children":[{"parentId":268,"children":[{"parentId":270,"children":null}]},{"parentId":268,"children":[{"parentId":269,"children":null}]}]}]}]

function add(data, obj) {
  data.forEach(e => {
    Object.assign(e, obj);
    if (e.children) add(e.children, obj)
  })
}

add(data, {open: 'fa fa-open'})
console.log(data)
```